# Pivot in Vertica - From Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have a table that looks like that:

| ID | completion_Rate - step1 | completion_Rate - step2 | completion_Rate - step3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 0 | 29 | 54 |
| id2 | 0 | 22 | 76 |

I want to Pivot it to that:

| ID | step_number | completion_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id1 | 2 | 29 |
| id1 | 3 | 54 |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 22 |
| id3 | 3 | 76 |

I know we don't have Pivot function in Vertica, but maybe there is a smart way to do it?

(If not, I'll take it a step back, the original table looks like that:

| id | completion_rates |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 0_29_54 |
| id2 | 0_22_76 |

So if there is another way to "explode" this string into rows, that doesn't use split part to convert to columns first it will also help me.
)

I tried splitting into columns, but now I don't find a way to pivot

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there are two ways to do it.

If you have large number of columns then maybe use some script to generate the SQL.

**Option 1:**

```sql
WITH input_data (id, completion_rate)
AS (
    SELECT 'id1', '0_29_54'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'id2', '0_22_76'
    )
SELECT id, position + 1 as step_number, completion_rate FROM (
SELECT EXPLODE(id, STRING_TO_ARRAY(split_part(completion_rate, '_', 1) 
    || ',' || split_part(completion_rate, '_', 2) 
    || ',' || split_part(completion_rate, '_', 3))::Array [int]) 
    OVER (PARTITION BEST) AS (
        id
        , position
        , completion_rate
        ) FROM input_data
) sub;

 id  | step_number | completion_rate
-----+-------------+-----------------
 id1 |           1 |               0
 id1 |           2 |              29
 id1 |           3 |              54
 id2 |           1 |               0
 id2 |           2 |              22
 id2 |           3 |              76
(6 rows)
```

**Option 2:**

```sql
WITH input_data (id, completion_rate)
AS (
    SELECT 'id1', '0_29_54'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'id2', '0_22_76'
    )
SELECT id
    , 1 as step_number
    , split_part(completion_rate, '_', 1) as completion_rate
FROM input_data

UNION ALL 

SELECT id
    , 2 as step_number
    , split_part(completion_rate, '_', 2) as completion_rate
FROM input_data

UNION ALL 

SELECT id
    , 3 as step_number
    , split_part(completion_rate, '_', 3) as completion_rate
FROM input_data
;


 id  | step_number | completion_rate
-----+-------------+-----------------
 id1 |           1 | 0
 id2 |           1 | 0
 id1 |           2 | 29
 id2 |           2 | 22
 id1 |           3 | 54
 id2 |           3 | 76
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer un-pivoting a delimited string with either and `EXPLODE()` on a `STRING_TO_ARRAY()`, as from @minatverma, or by `CROSS JOIN`-ing with a series of consecutive integers, and using `SPLIT_PART()`:

```
WITH
-- your input 
indata(id,completion_rates) AS (
          SELECT 'id1','0_29_54'
UNION ALL SELECT 'id2','0_22_76'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
-- four consecutive integers - one too many ...
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
  UNION ALL SELECT 4
)
SELECT
  id
, i  AS step_number
, SPLIT_PART(completion_rates,'_',i) AS completion_rate
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
WHERE completion_rate <> '' -- filter out any empty results ...
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| id | step_number | completion_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id1 | 2 | 29 |
| id1 | 3 | 54 |
| id2 | 1 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 22 |
| id2 | 3 | 76 |

Answer (score 0):

There's yet another way of doing that - in only one query:
Convert the underscore-delimited string to an array, and explode it.

```
WITH
-- your input 
indata(id,completion_rates) AS (
          SELECT 'id1','0_29_54'
UNION ALL SELECT 'id2','0_22_76'
)
SELECT
  EXPLODE(
    id
  , STRING_TO_ARRAY(completion_rates USING PARAMETERS collection_delimiter='_')
  ) OVER(PARTITION BEST)
FROM indata
ORDER BY 1;
```

| id | position | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 0 | 0 |
| id1 | 1 | 29 |
| id1 | 2 | 54 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 |
| id2 | 1 | 22 |
| id2 | 2 | 76 |